# Random Forest using one variable

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree, feature-selection

I am trying to determine the optimal group of variables for a classification task. Sometimes instead of a group of variables, only a single variable should be selected (but the data was pretty weak looking at each variable alone).

I used several classifiers (Random Forest, Logistic regression, SVM) and I have a small problem in understanding the results (the best results were achieved by using RF).

Can someone with a deeper conceptual understanding of random forest than me please explain what a random forest using one variable is doing? Since it is only one variable, it is hard for me to see how the random forest can achieve a better sens/spec than that single variable can ever achieve alone (which it does). Is (in this case) the RF a decision tree? I was thinking that it might be the case, and after testing I observed that all the scores (accuracy, F1, precision, recall) were the same for the two of them.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: please clarify - in your 2nd para you claim that the best results among many classifiers (including a decision tree) were obtained by RF, while later you say that RF & decision tree results were the same...

Comment: @desertnaut I edited the question, thank you for the observation. What I meant was that after I obtained the first results (in which the RF was the best) I ran another test (this time by using a decision tree) and I obtained exactly the same results. Hence the second question.